# Permissions issue on ext4 external drive

Tags: linux, bash, shell, files, permissions

I have come across a weird error with permissions with an external hard drive I attached to my server.  I wanted to enable Transmission to download torrents to a folder on it, but discovered it was unable to create directories due to permission errors.
I tested it myself and verified that the daemon, running as user `transmission`, can't create directories in a folder it owns with *755* permissions.
I thought it might be some weird inode shenanigans, but an `fsck` came back clean and everything looks normal.

```
matoro@matoro-server ~ $ ls -i /run/media/matoro/drive-data
total 40
43253761 drwxr-xr-x  5 matoro       matoro        4096 Apr 11  2017 backup
11796481 drwxr-xr-x  3 matoro       matoro        4096 Oct 28 22:40 iso
37568568 drwxr-xr-x  2 matoro       matoro        4096 Apr 23  2017 pending
42336296 drwxr-xr-x  3 matoro       matoro        4096 Oct 25 01:26 podcasts
38141969 drwxr-xr-x 39 matoro       matoro       12288 Sep 18 22:05 reading
37519377 drwxr-xr-x  3 transmission transmission  4096 Oct 30 17:10 seeding
37490784 drwxr-xr-x  4 matoro       matoro        4096 Oct 30 17:09 videos
42336292 drwxr-xr-x  3 matoro       matoro        4096 Oct 25 01:23 youtube
matoro@matoro-server ~ $ ls -ia /run/media/matoro/drive-data/seeding
total 912160
37519377 drwxr-xr-x  3 transmission transmission      4096 Oct 30 17:10  .
       2 drwxr-xr-x 11 matoro       matoro            4096 Nov  3 14:56  ..
37584902 drwxr-xr-x  3 transmission transmission      4096 Aug 10  2016 'some directory'
37488367 -rw-r--r--  1 transmission transmission 430297088 Aug 14  2016  some_file
matoro@matoro-server ~ $ sudo -u transmission mkdir -v /run/media/matoro/drive-data/seeding/test
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/run/media/matoro/drive-data/seeding/test’: Permission denied
```

Here are the relevant mount options:

```
/dev/sdc3 on /run/media/matoro/drive-data type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,data=ordered,uhelper=udisks2)
```

What could be causing this?  Could it have something to do with ACLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mkdir` command must traverse the directory structure to find the existing directory `/run/media/matoro/drive-data/seeding` and then add an entry to it. The required permissions are:

1. `x` permission on `/`
2. `x` permission on `/run`
3. `x` permission on `/run/media`
4. `x` permission on `/run/media/matoro`
5. `x` permission on `/run/media/matoro/drive-data`
6. `w` and `x` permission on `/run/media/matoro/drive-data/seeding`

(and of course they all must be directories, and the one you're creating must not already exist)

I bet you're missing one of these (probably #4 or #5)
If the process already had `/run/media/matoro/drive-data/seeding` as its current directory (which can happen if the ancestor directory permissions change after you enter the directory, or if the process switches uid) then it could `mkdir test` and succeed with only permission #6 (`w` and `x` on the current directory) while `mkdir /run/media/matoro/drive-data/seeding/test` would require all of the `x` permissions, even though it refers to the same location.

When you use absolute paths, or relative paths with multiple components, there is an `x` permission check on every ancestor directory that you mention.

Comment: Yup, looks like #4 was the culprit.  My understanding is that the structure of `/run` should be handled by the init system - what is the best way of going about giving other users access to external drives?

Comment: The permission octal 1777 gives everyone write access to shared directories, while reserving delete rights for the file/directory owner. 1755 would reserve write permissions as well. I usually go with 1777 for my shared directories. This also works for files on external drives.